# unresponsive -- operator in a for loop with multiple variables C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

Just as the title says, I have a waveManaging system that spawnsEnemies based on enemies that are yet to spawn and remain alive.

```
for (int enemiesRemainingToSpawn = currentWaveNumber ; enemiesRemainingToSpawn > 0;enemiesRemainingToSpawn -- , enemiesRemainingAlive ++)
    {
        print("enemies spawning" + enemiesRemainingToSpawn);
        print("enemies alive" + enemiesRemainingAlive);
    }
```

This is just a test right now, but it seems that 'enemiesRemaingToSpawn --' is not working while 'enemiesRemainingAlive ++' is.

On the GameDev Discord, no one has found anything wrong with it which is why I am here. It looks fine to me as well. I have tried putting it within the body of the loop but that does not work as well. i have specified it within the initializing(first) section of the for loop and again this does not work.

What is the problem at hand?

edit:

```
public int enemiesRemainingToSpawn;
public int enemiesRemainingAlive;
public float afterWavePrepTime = 5f;
public GameObject basicEnemyPreFab;
public Transform[] spawnPoints;


private bool isWaveFinished = false;
private bool startNewWave = false;
public int currentWaveNumber;

void spawnEnemies ()
{
    int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

    for (int enemiesRemainingToSpawn = currentWaveNumber ; enemiesRemainingToSpawn > 0;enemiesRemainingToSpawn -- , enemiesRemainingAlive ++)
    {
        print("enemies spawning" + enemiesRemainingToSpawn);
        print("enemies alive" + enemiesRemainingAlive);
    }
}
```

The output is that enemiesRemainingAlive constantly goes up because EnemiesRemainingToSpawn does not go down, concluding in an endless loop.
remainingtospawn = 1, enemiesremainingalive ++

Comment: Can you include the starting values for all the various variables and the output you get.  I don't see any reason why `enemiesRemaingToSpawn ` shouldn't get decremented in each loop

Comment: InEdit, I dont know why too haha

Comment: The problem has to lie somewhere else. I just copy pasted your code without any changes into a new project and it works! Output: (for enemiesRemainingToSpawn=3 and enemiesRemainingAlive=0) `enemies spawning3`, `enemies alive0`, `enemies spawning2`, `enemies alive1`, `enemies spawning1`, `enemies alive2`. Anyway you should be careful: your for declaration declares also a new variable `enemiesRemainingToSpawn` that overrides your public variable. Rather skip the `int` to reuse the public variable! (`for( enemiesRemainingTospawn= .....`)

Comment: are you calling `spawnEnemies` from some other loop?

Comment: no not at all. I havent referenced it anywhere else

Comment: If you suspect the coma is the culprit, switch the statements like so:
    `for (int enemiesRemainingToSpawn = currentWaveNumber ; enemiesRemainingToSpawn > 0;enemiesRemainingAlive ++, enemiesRemainingToSpawn -- )`
if the problem still occurs, your problem resides somewhere else and we can't tell you without further knowledges of your project.

Comment: By any chance, does `spawnEnemies` is called from within a loop ? And `enemiesRemainingToSpawn` is set to `1` just before ? If this is the case, your loop is not the problem but the parent loop. To check that, just add a `Debug.Log(enemiesRemainingToSpawn)` before the loop in `spawnEnemies` and tell us the result. Can you show us the script where you call `spawnEnemies` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I try to run your code in locally by excluding your objects .Its running well

```js
 public static void spawnEnemies()
        {
         
         int enemiesRemainingAlive = 0;
         double afterWavePrepTime = 5.0;
       
         bool isWaveFinished = false;
         bool startNewWave = false;
         int currentWaveNumber;

        
            Random x = new Random();
             currentWaveNumber = x.Next(1, 7);

            for (int enemiesRemainingToSpawn = currentWaveNumber; enemiesRemainingToSpawn > 0; enemiesRemainingToSpawn--, enemiesRemainingAlive++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enemies spawning" + enemiesRemainingToSpawn);
                    Console.WriteLine("enemies alive" + enemiesRemainingAlive);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

           
        }

        //out put
        // enemies spawning2
        //enemies alive0
        //enemies spawning1
        //enemies alive1
```